# Usar if y function para una calculadora

Tags: javascript, condiciones, function, matemáticas

Estoy realizando la siguiente calculadora, y necesito usar `if` y funciones. Estaba pensando en el siguiente código, pero no he podido lograr que funcione.

Mi idea es que al dar `onclick` desencadene una función que tenga los condicionales de acuerdo al botón que presione, el de suma, resta, multiplicación y división;

```js
function operacion() {

  var suma, multip, resta, divi;
  suma = document.getElementById("suma");
  multip = document.getElementById("multip");
  resta = document.getElementById("resta");
  divi = document.getElementById("divi");

  if (onclick = suma) {

    function suma() {
      var num1, num2;
      num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor").value);
      num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor2").value);
      var sumado = num1 + num2;
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "la suma de " + num1 + " mas " + num2 + " es " +
        sumado;
    }
  } else if (onclick = multiplicacion) {
    function multiplicacion(num1, num2) {
      num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor").value);
      num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor2").value);
      var mult = num1 * num2;
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Multiplicar " + num1 + " por " + num2 + " da como resultado " +
        mult;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculadora</h1>
<div class="vis">
 <p>Introduce el primer valor
  <input class="valores" type="text" id="valor"></p>
 <p>Introduce el segundo valor
  <input class="valores" type="text" id="valor2"></p>
 <input id="suma" class="botones" type="button" value="+" 
onclick="operacion()">
 <input id="multip" class="botones" type="button" value="x" 
onclick="operacion()">
 <br />
 <p id="resultado"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: David échale un ojo a esta liga a lo mejor es mejor utilizar switch que if-else https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch

Comment: Buenas noches, César. Gracias por tu respuesta. Desafortunadamente como es una tarea, tengo que usar if y funciones, ya había resuelto como terminarlo, pero no usé ningún if, también vi usar switch, y creo que sería lo que más me convendría, pero no puedo usarlos de momento. ):

Comment: De nada David espero que te sirva, disculpa que no te ponga un ejemplo propio pero ese código lo tengo en la oficina y al final esta sentencia es como si hicieras un "menu" si no tienes prisa mañana lo busco y te pongo lo que en su momento utilice para hacer una especie de CRUD

Comment: Ten en cuenta que como en _JavaScript_ todo es sensible a mayúsculas, `Function` es una función para crear funciones, mientras que `function` la palabra reservada para crear funciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te muestro cómo lo haría yo. Mi estructura *HTML* será la siguiente:

```
<h1>Calculadora</h1>
<div>Introduce el primer valor: <input /></div>
<div>Introduce el segundo valor: <input /></div>
<button>+</button> 
<button>x</button> 
<button>-</button> 
<button>/</button> 
<p/> Resultado: <input disabled>
```

Te preguntarás a dónde fueron a parar todos los atributos. Bueno, es que no los necesito, hice una función llamada `buscar` para ubicar cada elemento sin necesidad de conocer el `id`, y permite *buscar* un elemento *HTML*.

¿Qué hace cada parámetro de la función `buscar`?

- `etiqueta`: Busca mediante una ruta *CSS*. Para lograr esto se usa `document.querySelectorAll`, y luego se le aplica `Array.from` para convertir la lista de encontrados a un `Array`.
- `texto`: Filtra por lo que haya dentro de tal elemento. Si este parámetro es diferente a un `String` vacío (`!=""`), se filtra por lo que hay dentro de la etiqueta *HTML*, es decir, su contenido. Pero si el *String* está vacío (`==""`), no hace ese filtro:

  ```
  if(texto!=""){
      por_texto = por_texto.filter(function(x){return x.innerHTML==texto})
  }
  ```
- `posición`: Elige la `posición` para elegir uno de todos los elementos encontrados.

Función `buscar`:

```
function buscar(etiqueta,texto,posición){
    var por_etiqueta = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(etiqueta))
    var por_texto = por_etiqueta
    if(texto!=""){
        por_texto = por_texto.filter(function(x){return x.innerHTML==texto})
    }
    return por_texto[posición]
}
```

Esta función permite *buscar* los botones que son los operadores de los cálculos y los `input` de los valores que se ingresarán. Ejemplo, para buscar el *botón* (`button`) de multiplicar se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
window.multip  = buscar("button","x",0)
```

Nota: Esta asignación se hará de una manera un poco más compleja usando `map`. De esta manera se pueden hacer asignaciones en serie.

- El primer parámetro busca todos los botones, es decir, los de etiqueta `button`.
- El segundo, de todos esos botones, elige solo el que tenga una **x**, que es el signo de multiplicar.
- El tercer parámetro:

  - **Como es un *0*, se elige el *primer elemento*** de los encontrados.
  - Si hubiera sido un *1*, se elige el segundo encontrado.
  - Tampoco fue *2*, de haber sido así, habría sido *el tercero*.
  - ... y así sucesivamente.

Hago una función para asignar variables globales en serie, para buscar mediante un *array* los elementos *HTML*:

```
function asignar(serie){
    serie.map(x=>window[x[0]]=buscar(x[3]?"input":"button",x[1],x[2]))
}
```

Los parámetros son los mismos que los anteriores, solo que ahora se agrega el cuarto parámetro, que determina el nombre de la etiqueta del elemento que se busca.

Si el último parámetro, que es el cuarto, y a su vez es `x[3]`, es:

- Un *0*, se busca un `button`.
- Un *1*, se busca un `input`.

  ```
                         +----- Parámetro de posición.
                         | +--- Este es el cuarto parámetro.
                         V V
  asignar([["suma"  ,"+",0,0]
          ,["multip","x",0,0]
          ,["resta" ,"-",0,0]
          ,["divi"  ,"/",0,0]])
  ```

Asignando variables para los `input` que servirán para ingresar los valores:

```
asignar([["valor_1","",0,1]
        ,["valor_2","",1,1]])
```

Asignando una variable para el `input` donde se verá el resultado:

```
asignar([["resu","",2,1]])
```

Otra variable pero esta vez para el operador seleccionado:

```
window.operador = "+"
```

Para que el usuario sepa qué operador está activado, se lo marca con un fondo verde (aunque bien podría ser de otro color):

```
window.suma.style["background-color"] = "#80ff80"
```

Mediante `addEventListener` asignamos eventos equivalentes a los atributos *HTML* `onClick` y `onKeyUp`. A los botones (`button`) les asignamos `click` y a los `input` en los que se ingresan los valores, asignamos `keyup`:

```
var eventos = [
   ["suma"   ,0], ["multip" ,0], ["resta",0], ["divi",0]
  ,["valor_1",1], ["valor_2",1]
].map(
  x=>window[x[0]].addEventListener(x[1]?"keyup":"click",function(){
    operacion(this)
  })
)
```

Para aplicar lo mismo a cada elemento de la lista usamos `map`. Ejemplo, si la lista es `["valor_1", "valor_2" ]`, le aplicamos lo mismo a `"valor_1"` y a `"valor_2"`.

La variable `this` la usamos para enviar como parámetro el botón (`button`) seleccionado a la función que va a realizar la operación matemática y así poder saber si tiene que hacer una suma o resta, o la operación que sea.

#### Función `operación`:

Es una función que usa `eval` para realizar el cálculo matemático.

> Se concatena (se unen) el **primer valor** ingresado, el **operador** y el **segundo valor**.

Es decir:

```
window.resu.value = eval( val_1 + operador + val_2 )
```

Código de la función `operacion`:

```
function operacion(botón){
    if(botón.tagName.toLowerCase()=="button"){
        ["suma", "multip", "resta", "divi"].map(function(x){
            window[x].style["background-color"] = ""
        })
        botón.style["background-color"] = "#80ff80"
        window.operador = botón.textContent
        if(window.operador=="x"){
            window.operador="*"
        }
    }
    var val_1 = window.valor_1.value
    var val_2 = window.valor_2.value
    try{
        window.resu.value = eval( val_1 + operador + val_2 )
    }catch(e){}
}
```

1. Se comprueba si se hizo click en algún botón.

   ```
   if(botón.tagName.toLowerCase()=="button"){
   ```

   Si se hizo click en algún botón realiza varias acciones:

   - Se quita el fondo verde a todos los botones y luego se aplica el fondo verde al botón seleccionado.

     ```
     ["suma", "multip", "resta", "divi"].map(function(x){
         window[x].style["background-color"] = ""
     })
     botón.style["background-color"] = "#80ff80"
     ```
   - Define el texto que hay dentro del botón seleccionado, para saber cuál es el que botón que se eligió.

     ```
     window.operador = botón.textContent
     ```
   - Si se eligió el de multiplicar, se adapta a la operación *JavaScript*, cambiando la **`x`** por un asterisco **`*`**. De esta manera se puede multiplicar mediante `eval`.

     ```
     if(window.operador=="x"){
         window.operador="*"
     }
     ```
2. Se obtienen los valores ingresados:

   ```
   var val_1 = window.valor_1.value
   var val_2 = window.valor_2.value
   ```
3. El último paso: Se intenta realizar la operación mediante `eval` concatenando los valores ingresados y en el centro el operador matemático:

   ```
   try{
       window.resu.value = eval( val_1 + operador + val_2 )
   }catch(e){}
   ```

Código completo:

```js
function buscar(etiqueta,texto,posición){
  var por_etiqueta = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(etiqueta))
  var por_texto = por_etiqueta
  if(texto!=""){
    por_texto = por_texto.filter(function(x){return x.innerHTML==texto})
  }
  return por_texto[posición]
}
function asignar(serie){
  serie.map(x=>window[x[0]]=buscar(x[3]?"input":"button",x[1],x[2]))
}

asignar([ ["suma"   ,"+",0,0]
         ,["multip" ,"x",0,0]
         ,["resta"  ,"-",0,0]
         ,["divi"   ,"/",0,0]
         ,["valor_1","" ,0,1]
         ,["valor_2","" ,1,1]
         ,["resu"   ,"" ,2,1] ])

window.operador = "+"
window.suma.style["background-color"] = "#80ff80"

var eventos = [
   ["suma"   ,0], ["multip" ,0], ["resta",0], ["divi",0]
  ,["valor_1",1], ["valor_2",1]
].map(
  x=>window[x[0]].addEventListener(x[1]?"keyup":"click",function(){
    operacion(this)
  })
)

function operacion(botón){
  if(botón.tagName.toLowerCase()=="button"){
    ["suma", "multip", "resta", "divi"].map(function(x){
      window[x].style["background-color"] = ""
    })
    botón.style["background-color"] = "#80ff80"
    window.operador = botón.textContent
    if(window.operador=="x"){
      window.operador="*"
    }
  }
  var val_1 = window.valor_1.value
  var val_2 = window.valor_2.value
  try{
    window.resu.value = eval( val_1 + operador + val_2 )
  }catch(e){}
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculadora</h1>
<div>Introduce el primer valor: <input /></div>
<div>Introduce el segundo valor: <input /></div>
<button>+</button> 
<button>x</button> 
<button>-</button> 
<button>/</button> 
<p/> Resultado: <input disabled=true>
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta quitando el onclick

```
function operacion() {

        var suma, multip, resta, divi;
        suma = document.getElementById("suma");
        multip = document.getElementById("multip");
        resta = document.getElementById("resta");
        divi = document.getElementById("divi");

        if (suma) {
function suma() {
                var num1, num2;
                num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor").value);
                num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor2").value);
                var sumado = num1 + num2;
                document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "la suma de " + num1 + " mas " + num2 + " es " +
                    sumado;
            }
```

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer], editar y explicar tu aporte no caería mal